# iOS _OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManage referenced from: objc-class-ref in ViewController.o

Tags: ios, linker-errors

I am trying to launch a WebView in iOS and transmit the IDFA as part of a GET request but when I try to build it fails and I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is the code I have.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong here, I am a bit stuck

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "AdSupport/ASIdentifierManager.h"

    @interface ViewController ()
    @end

    @implementation ViewController
    @synthesize webView;



    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        NSString *idfaString = [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];

    webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"];
    NSString *param = [url.path stringByAppendingString: idfaString];
    NSURL *send = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:param];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:send];

    [webView loadRequest:req];


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
   {
       [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make sure `ASIdentifierManager.m` is checked under "Target Membership" for your project's target.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. This was in the right direction. I did not have the AdSupport.framework listed under 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' which can be modified in Xcode under the Tragets --> General section.

Answer (score 32):

In case you are as stupid as me, don't forget to add `AdSupport.framework` in your project too.

Comment: For me I was trying to build a static library. Which has AdSupport in it. Good to note that you also need AdSupport.framework in the app using the library

Comment: i also forget to add the AdSupport.framework in my project